# onboard ethernet card does not work

Tags: ethernet

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, my motherboard got damaged, so I have to replace it with a new motherboard. I connected the hard disk to the new motherboard. My external Ethernet cards are working, but the Ethernet card in the motherboard is not working.

If I give sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart

It shows: Ignoring unknown interface eth0=eth0

Intel Mother board

If I give `lspci -v`. I get the following output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express DRAM Controller (rev 10)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express PCI Express Root Port (rev 10) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 10) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    Memory at ff900000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    I/O ports at f140 [size=8]
    Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at ff600000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Expansion ROM at  [disabled]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device d608
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at ff980000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: e4200000-e43fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e4400000-00000000e45fffff
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: ff800000-ff8fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e4000000-00000000e41fffff
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    I/O ports at f080 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    I/O ports at f020 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at ff984000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=32
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
    Memory behind bridge: ff700000-ff7fffff
    Capabilities: 

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation DeskTop Board D945GTP
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel modules: leds-ss4200, iTCO_wdt, intel-rng

00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    I/O ports at 01f0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 03f4 [size=1]
    I/O ports at 0170 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 0374 [size=1]
    I/O ports at f0f0 [size=16]
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix

00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01) (prog-if 8f [Master SecP SecO PriP PriO])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    I/O ports at f0e0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f0d0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f0c0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f0b0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f0a0 [size=16]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device d608
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 10
    I/O ports at f000 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c-i801

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device d608
    Physical Slot: 2
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Memory at ff820000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Expansion ROM at ff800000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8168, r8169

04:05.0 Ethernet controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6105/VT6106S [Rhine-III] (rev 8b)
    Subsystem: D-Link System Inc Device 1405
    Flags: bus master, stepping, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 20
    I/O ports at d100 [size=256]
    Memory at ff700100 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: via-rhine
    Kernel modules: via-rhine

04:06.0 Ethernet controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6105/VT6106S [Rhine-III] (rev 8b)
    Subsystem: D-Link System Inc Device 1405
    Flags: bus master, stepping, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 21
    I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
    Memory at ff700000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: via-rhine
    Kernel modules: via-rhine
```

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: please post your lspci -v output

Comment: @Danatela: I have added more information about my hardware.

Comment: @Babinlonston: I have added the information that you have asked from me.

Comment: I think you have option in your BIOS that should enable onboard card. Check it.

Comment: @Danatela: There are two Kernel modules: r8168, r8169, but Kernel driver in use: r8169 only, would that be a problem?

Comment: @Danatela: I have checked the BIOS, onboard usb is in 'enable' condition.

Comment: If I give sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart

It shows: Ignoring unknown interface eth0=eth0

Comment: And what shows `sudo ifconfig eth0 up`? Onboard USB is not you have to search for. What about Onboard LAN?

Comment: @Danatela: Sorry, I meant only about Onboard LAN. Also If I give 'sudo ifconfig eth0 up' It shows nothing.